# Entity Framework Code Generation for particular table

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have created Database by using Entity framework Database first approach. Its is working good but I added a new table in database and then I update the model but I can't find code for that particular table. It is my first time to do like this.

Is there a shortcut to update and generate code for particular table. Because I have lot of tables for my project. I can't delete and create code from start.

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating entity framework tables.save the project and right click  the `.tt` file under `.edmx` and `Run Custom Tool` this will generate class for newly added tables and modification on existing tables.

[Click here for more details](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/08/entity-framework-manual-update.html#.U04Ec_mSwtF)